# naudio - Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data

Tags: naudio

I'm writing a program that contains a simple MP3/WAV media player area.

I've followed the code contained within the NAudio sample programs and this is the class I created to encapsulate a playable audio file:

```
public sealed class PlaybackContext : IDisposable {

    private String         _fileName;
    private DirectSoundOut _dsoundOut;
    private WaveStream     _waveStream;

    public PlaybackContext(String fileName) {

        _fileName  = fileName;
        _dsoundOut = new DirectSoundOut( DirectSoundOut.DSDEVID_DefaultPlayback );

        String ext = Path.GetExtension( fileName );
        if( ext.Equals(".mp3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ) {

            _waveStream = new Mp3FileReader( fileName );

        } else if( ext.Equals(".wav", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ) {

            _waveStream = new WaveFileReader( fileName );
            switch( _waveStream.WaveFormat.Encoding ) {
                case WaveFormatEncoding.Pcm:
                case WaveFormatEncoding.IeeeFloat:
                    break;
                default:
                    _waveStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream( WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream( _waveStream ) );
                    break;
            }
        }

        _dsoundOut.Init( _waveStream );
    }

    public void Play() {

        _dsoundOut.Play();
    }
            // hidden are the Pause/Stop/Dispose methods
```

It works fine for MP3 files, but when I try to play any Wave files I get this exception:

```
Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data.
   System.ArgumentException
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.InternalAlloc(Object value, GCHandleType type)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(Object value, GCHandleType type)
   at NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut.InitializeDirectSound()
   at NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut.PlaybackThreadFunc()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I can't find anything with Google, and my code is compiled for x86 (so this isn't a 64-bit issue). Otherwise I'm stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you play using DirectSound with the NAudioDemo app that comes with NAudio?

Comment: Wow, Mark himself :) - Yes, the NAudioDemo.exe program can play WAV files fine.

Comment: hmmm, not sure what is going on then. Any particular reason you needed to use DirectSound instead of WaveOut? Are you using the latest NAudio?

Comment: I downloaded the latest build from CodePlex and the exception still happens, but NAudio now swallows it silently. The exception is thrown in DirectSoundOut.cs, line 248.

Comment: The argument to GCHandle.Alloc is WaveFormatExtraData instance, btw.

Comment: not sure why WaveFormatExtraData would be non-blittable, but can you construct a regular WaveFormat with the format you would like to use instead?